# aws redshift - how to retrieve out parameters(metadata) of stored procedure

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Please give a query to retrieve out parameters for a particular stored procedure by using a sql query in aws redshift, as i want to retrieve metadata of a particular stored procedure which has parameters ,thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve out parameters"? Are you saying that you want to get information back when _calling_ a stored procedure? It comes back immediately after the `call`. See: [Overview of stored procedures in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi , just wanted a sql query which will list out the parameters of a stored procedure which means it is the metadata of the particular stored procedure . thank you